# managing loader id uniqueness

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-loadermanager, android-cursorloader

I'm finding that my CursorLoader callbacks are getting mixed up cursors.

The problem seems to be that

Fragment.getLoaderManager() is the same loader id scope as getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager()

from AOSP

```
public LoaderManager getLoaderManager() {
    if (mLoaderManager != null) {
        return mLoaderManager;
    }
    if (mActivity == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Fragment " + this + " not attached to Activity");
    }
    mCheckedForLoaderManager = true;
    mLoaderManager = mActivity.getLoaderManager(mIndex, mLoadersStarted, true);
    return mLoaderManager;
}
```

so what I'm experiencing is ID conflict amongst my fragments, so the wrong cursors are hoping across fragments.

I need a strategy to create both static and/or dynamic(in the case of dynamic amounts of loaders) id's that are aware of every other fragments ids...?

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example of what the problem you are having is? It is true that if you look at the source code the `Fragment`s share the same underlying loader manager instance, but you should still be able to distinguish between each fragment's distinct set of loaders (even if they have the same ids).

Comment: For example just say I have a fragment the loads up a particular table of data with perhaps different filters. And I have 2 instances of the same fragment in the same activity (multi-pane). If I set the loader id to be 0, then it's zero for both, and the cursor callbacks get muddled up.

Comment: Just double checking... did you call `initLoader()` inside your `Fragment`s `onCreate()` method? Make sure you don't do that. Initialize your fragments' loaders in `onActivityCreated()` instead.

Comment: Yeah I'm doing that, the problem is providing unique loader Ids. The only thing I can think of is to perhaps have the fragment to ask the activity for a loader ID that isn't in use and store that.. But I think loader IDs need to be stable across activity destruction eg. rotation. Maybe need something even higher than than, some kind of singleton that survives the entire app, it's overkill considering the scope is only the activity, but it's the only thing that would survive the destruction of the activity, maintain stable IDs but also provide dynamic IDs needed for some layouts...

Comment: Actually, even a singleton couldn't provide stable IDs unless it knew intimately the details of the fragment requesting the ID to be generated... ie some of the bundle details... ergh.. why couldn't they just make the scope unique to the fragment!!!!

Comment: You should be able to have multiple fragments with loaders containing identical IDs and not have any problems. I think there is just something wrong with your code that is causing the callbacks to get mixed up...

Comment: Hrmm I think you might be right, the mIndex I think implies unique loader IDs. I think my problem might be due to sue of fragments in fragments... It'll take me a while to isolate this if that's true

Answer (score 4):

You can have same id in different fragments for your loaders as long as you are using fragment.getLoader().  Follow the ASOP code a bit deeper and you'll see that

```
mLoaderManager = mActivity.getLoaderManager(mIndex, mLoadersStarted, true);
```

calls into a package private method that gets a loader from a ArrayMap of loaders.  mIndex(unique string for the fragment) is index  for that ArrayMap and is unique to fragment.  Looking at Activity implementation of getLoader() you'll see that it does this:

```
mLoaderManager = mActivity.getLoaderManager("(root)", mLoadersStarted, true);
```

Clearly Activity has it's own loader, as well as each fragment.  The problem lies somewhere else in the code.